# Not able to correctly set the default value of a dropdownbutton in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

My flutter dropdownbutton code is:-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class MyStatesDropdown extends StatelessWidget {
  final String value;
  final Function(String newValue) onChanged;
  final List<Map<String, String>> items;

  MyStatesDropdown(
      {super.key,
      required this.value,
      required this.onChanged,
      required this.items});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Obx(() => Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Center(
                child: DropdownButtonFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  isDense: true,
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
                  hintText: 'Select State',
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade800)),
              value: value,
              onChanged: (newVal) => onChanged(newVal ?? ''),
              items: items.map((Map item) {
                return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: item['scode'], child: Text(item['sname']));
              }).toList(),
              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
              iconSize: 42,
            )),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

My GetX controller looks like:-

```
.................
  final istates = [
    {'scode': '35', 'sname': 'Andaman & Nicobar Islands'},
    {'scode': '37', 'sname': 'Andhra Pradesh'},
    {'scode': '12', 'sname': 'Arunachal Pradesh'},
    {'scode': '18', 'sname': 'Assam'},
    {'scode': '10', 'sname': 'Bihar'},
    {'scode': '04', 'sname': 'Chandigarh'},
    {'scode': '22', 'sname': 'Chattisgarh'},
    {'scode': '26', 'sname': 'Dadra & Nagar Haveli & Daman & Diu'},
    {'scode': '07', 'sname': 'Delhi'},
    {'scode': '30', 'sname': 'Goa'},
    {'scode': '24', 'sname': 'Gujarat'},
    {'scode': '06', 'sname': 'Haryana'},
    {'scode': '02', 'sname': 'Himachal Pradesh'},
    {'scode': '01', 'sname': 'Jammu & Kashmir'},
    {'scode': '20', 'sname': 'Jharkhand'},
    {'scode': '29', 'sname': 'Karnataka'},
    {'scode': '32', 'sname': 'Kerala'},
    {'scode': '38', 'sname': 'Ladakh'},
    {'scode': '31', 'sname': 'Lakshwadeep'},
    {'scode': '23', 'sname': 'Madhya Pradesh'},
    {'scode': '27', 'sname': 'Maharashtra'},
    {'scode': '14', 'sname': 'Manipur'},
    {'scode': '17', 'sname': 'Meghalaya'},
    {'scode': '15', 'sname': 'Mizoram'},
    {'scode': '13', 'sname': 'Nagaland'},
    {'scode': '21', 'sname': 'Odisha'},
    {'scode': '34', 'sname': 'Puducherry'},
    {'scode': '03', 'sname': 'Punjab'},
    {'scode': '08', 'sname': 'Rajasthan'},
    {'scode': '11', 'sname': 'Sikkim'},
    {'scode': '33', 'sname': 'Tamil Nadu'},
    {'scode': '36', 'sname': 'Telangana'},
    {'scode': '16', 'sname': 'Tripura'},
    {'scode': '09', 'sname': 'Uttar Pradesh'},
    {'scode': '15', 'sname': 'Uttrakhand'},
    {'scode': '19', 'sname': 'West Bengal'}
  ];

  var selectedStateSA = ''.obs;

  void updtSelectedStateSA(String val) {
    selectedStateSA.value = val;
  }

...............
```

Calling the dropdownbutton from an another screen like:-

```
...........
MyStatesDropdown(
    value:
        _genContllr.selectedStateSA.value,
    onChanged: (newValue) => _genContllr
        .updtSelectedStateSA(newValue),
    items: _genContllr.istates),

...........
```

Error: At compile time there is no error, but when the app is run the following error message is shown in place of the dropdownbutton

```
'Package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart':Failed assertion : line 1606 pos 15: items==null || items.isEmpty || value==null || items.where ((DropdownMenuItem <T> item){
return item.value == value;}).length == 1': There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value:. Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownButton]'s were detected with the same value.
See also: https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/errors
```

Any suggestions please as how should I initialize the default selected value of the dropdownbutton.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Also, your title that starts with *Problem with* is useless. Your title should not contain tag information, and should be clear and descriptive enough that a future site user skimming a list of search results will know what it contains. For suggestions about writing s good title, see [ask].

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I have edited my question as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

For `DropDownButton` there must be a selected value from your list. It's not a problem of GetX, it's a known limitation of the component itself.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was not aware of the limitation of the component. Even though I can try to achieve the functionality of the dropdown using BottomSheets, but thought that using dropdown would be easier.